# Add row to table and change its background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tablerow

I have an html string that I want to append to a table as a row using jquery, and I also want to change the background colour of this newly added row to red. This is what I've currently got for simply adding the row without the background colour:

```
$(outputString).appendTo('#billTable tbody').hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

But when I try using the code below, I get an error saying "Uncaught syntax error, unexpected string":

```
$(outputString).appendTo('#billTable tbody').css({"background-
color":"red"}).hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

Any clues on how to add in the background colour?

Comment: That should work as-is; so what's `outputString`?

Comment: Well, I just put in my original code again, refreshed the page, and it miraculously started working! outputString is just an html output which contains rows and columns of data received from a php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm that's weird - your code should work as it is. You could try using this instead:

```
$(outputString).appendTo('#billTable tbody').css('background-color', 'red').hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

I've replaced

```
.css({"background-color":"red"})
```

with

```
.css('background-color', 'red')
```

Comment: Very weird. This must be a jQuery bug. The multi-input of `css()` should not affect what input it get's from the pipe output of `appendTo()`. Glad it worked tho, and good to know :)